# Dynamics AX 2012 AIF QueryService through C# - Relations and JoinMode usage between multiple tables

Tags: c#, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, aif

I want to create a complex User defined AIF Query service by using Visual studio and writing code for query service in C#. I am using two custom tables among which one is header and one is line table. I have added fields in the query by using both the tables and applies proper ranges as well and it works fine. Now I want to make a relation between these two tables So I can fetch data based on relation.

Please help me out with how to make a relation between multiple tables in AIF query service.

```
query.DataSources = new QueryDataSourceMetadata[2];    
query.Name = "AXCustomerInfo";    
QueryDataSourceMetadata custTableDS = new QueryDataSourceMetadata();    
custTableDS.Name = "CustTable";    
custTableDS.Table = "CustTable";    
custTableDS.Enabled = true;    
query.DataSources[0] = custTableDS;    
custTableDS.DynamicFieldList = false;    
custTableDS.Fields = new QueryDataFieldMetadata[1];  
QueryDataFieldMetadata accountNum;    
accountNum = new QueryDataFieldMetadata();    
accountNum.FieldName = "AccountNum";
accountNum.SelectionField = SelectionField.Database;    
custTableDS.Fields[0] = accountNum;
custTableDS.HasRelations = true;
custTableDS.JoinMode =JoinMode.InnerJoin;
QueryDataSourceMetadata dirPartyTableDS = new QueryDataSourceMetadata();
dirPartyTableDS.Name = "DirPartyTable";
dirPartyTableDS.Table = "DirPartyTable";    
dirPartyTableDS.Enabled = true;    
query.DataSources[1] = dirPartyTableDS;    
dirPartyTableDS.DynamicFieldList = false;    
dirPartyTableDS.Fields = new QueryDataFieldMetadata[1];        
QueryDataFieldMetadata name;    
name = new QueryDataFieldMetadata();    
name.FieldName = "Name";    
name.SelectionField = SelectionField.Database;    
dirPartyTableDS.Fields[0] = name;    
dirPartyTableDS.HasRelations = false;        
result = client.ExecuteQuery(query, ref paging);
foreach (DataRow row in result.Tables[0].Rows)    
{    
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", row[0]));
    foreach (DataRow row1 in result.Tables[1].Rows)
    {    
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", row1[0]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [how to add multiple datasources to a query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/aa880078.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Either:

- Set the Relations property to Yes on the child data source.

or:

- Add a relation by doing the following:

  1. Set the Relations property to No on the child data source.
  2. Right-click the Relations node, and then click New Relation.
  3. Select a field from the parent data source in the Field property.
  4. Select a field from the child data source in the RelatedField property.
  5. Save all modifications.

You can then access the data of the query using [OData Query Service](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aif/2011/08/23/odata-query-service/).

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17406357/4509).

Comment: I am not using Axapta AOT to create the relation. All I have to do is to create a user defined Query in C# by using AIF query service. I have written full code in C# but I am unable to make a relation or join between two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Gaurav,

In your code, you are not creating a hierarchical structure of data sources. Hence relations will not work. You will get errors like : You can not add relation to root data source. I already shared my response on AX community. Here is the link: 
https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/p/212065/573674#573674

This will work.